# Postfix how to count all outgoing emails?

Tags: postfix-mta

Is it possible to count overall emails sent per day and save that value somewhere in a text file or in mysql?

I need to compare numbers of mails sent from website and mails sent directly or via mail clients.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can parse the log file to do that. There already exists a statistics tool for the Postfix log files called `pflogsumm`. Check it out here:
http://jimsun.linxnet.com/postfix_contrib.html

Or try some of the other analysis tools listed on the Postfix website:
http://www.postfix.org/addon.html#logfile